# Changing default YouTube account

Tags: youtube

Is there any way to permanently change the default YouTube account we're logged into right after loggin in to our master Google account? I have both a G+ and the "old" (non-Google) YouTube account linked to my Google account and every time I start a computer, I have to manually switch from the G+ one to the other one. Is there any option to choose which one I want and stick to it permanently?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. Google wants everyone to use one (G+) account on their products, so they make you use your primary google account after relogin.

Comment: I get my old account as first selection, so this probably not true.